# Keep Macro initiating drawing always on the screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scroll, drawing, google-sheets-macros

In my Google Sheets  I have two drawings, each of which executes a macro.  As I scroll through the sheet I would like the "drawing" to follow me so they always appear on the display so I can invoke them immediately.  Is there a way to make these "macro initiating drawings"  float so they are always on the screen?

Comment: most likely not possible

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, this is not possible. However, I would like to propose you two alternatives using Google Apps Script.

### Creating a menu

You can create a menu in Google Docs, Sheets, Slides or Forms using Google Apps Script.
In order to do so, you must create an `onOpen()` function containing code for the creation of it. Each of the buttons can execute different scripts that you may choose.

If you would like to create a menu with two options (one for the first drawing, and one for the second one) you could use a code similar to the following:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'yourFirstFunction')
      .addItem('Second item', 'yourSecondFunction')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Where `yourFirstFunction` and `yourSecondFunction` should be functions declared in your script. It would look like the following:

[image]

### Creating a sidebar

Sidebars can display HTML content (including images) so they may  be more akin to what you are trying to accomplish. In order to create them you will also need to use the `onOpen()` function to trigger its display:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Along with the declaration of the two functions, `yourFirstFunction()` and `yourSecondFunction()`.

You will also need to create your HTML file. You can create via File>New>HTML File, and for this example we will call it "Page". It will hold the following contents:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1eUiSE5jLHWQiOTQISbdsTxsOLgoOvxLM" width="250" onclick="google.script.run.yourFirstFunction()"/>
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pZCYQH1ZkxxL3Uvw8q9aHvp7cc7pWMAS" width="250" onclick="google.script.run.yourSecondFunction()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it holds two images, each of one calling their respective Google Apps Script functions. This would look like the following (of course you can use the images you please and customise the sidebar as much as you want using HTML5 and CSS3):
[image: example sidebar ui]

### References

- [Custom Menus in G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)